# MongoDB date range query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, express

I am using node.js and Mongo DB in my application.

I have stored date in a `field(datetime)` of an entry in a MongoDB as:

```
db.collection('person').insertOne({"name": "ABC","age": "40","datetime": Date()}
```

This outputs date as:`"datetime":"Mon Nov 21 2016 00:47:39 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"`

Now I am trying to find all entries which are greater than a particular date.
For this I do the following:

```
db.collection('person').find( {'datetime':{$gt: startingdate})
```

where startingdate contains `22,11,2016.`

This doesn't work and fetches me all the records that have a datetime field.

I even tried using :

```
startingdate = Date(22,11,2016)
```

and

```
startingdate = Date(2016,11,22)
```

but to no avail. Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `new Date()` instead of `Date()`.

`new Date()` returns date object whereas `Date()` returns string representation of datetime.

You need to send date object to MongoDB so that it can transform the date object to `ISODate`.

Comment: @AkashDivakarGore It *will* work, if you use the right syntax for the string you pass into the `new Date()` function.

Comment: @VinceBowdren: I have tried startingdate= new Date(2016-11-21T00:00:00Z) and also tried startingdate= new Date(2016-11-21).Could you highlight the right syntax for for the string to be passed? Thanks!

Comment: The value you pass in must be a string i.e. must be quoted.

Comment: The value is quoted !